# What is the meaning of this proposition for global residues?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I ran into the following proposition:

1. Given $P,H\in \mathbb{C}[z]$, $\text{res}_P(H)$ is linear in $H$ and is a rational function of the coefficients of $P$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$

where $\text{res}_P$ is the global residue, meaning
$$
\text{res}_P(H) = \sum_{\xi \in \mathbb{V}(P)} \text{res}_\xi(H/P)
$$

I understand that $\text{res}_P(-) : \mathbb{C}[z] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a linear map, so what is the meaning of the second part of the proposition?

Comment: so you don't understand my answer ?

Comment: @reuns No, I just didn't get to it yet. But thank you for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also called the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity) which is (up to $1/c_d$) polynomial in the coefficients of the denominator.

More precisely :
Let $ P(z) = \sum_{n=0}^d c_n z^n, Q(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{d-1}  \frac{c_n}{c_d} z^{d-n} = P(1/z) \frac{z^d}{c_d}-1$. Then $$\sum_{P(\alpha) = 0} Res(\frac{H(z)}{P(z)},\alpha) = \lim_{R \to \infty}\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z| = R} \frac{H(z)}{P(z)}dz=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z| = \epsilon} \frac{H(1/z)}{z^2 P(1/z)}dz$$ 
$$=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z| = \epsilon} \frac{c_d z^{d-2} H(1/z)}{1+Q(z)}dz=
\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|z| = \epsilon} c_d z^{d-2} H(1/z)(-Q(z))^mdz
\\=\sum_{m=0}^{deg(H)+1-d} Res(c_d z^{d-2} H(1/z)(-Q(z))^m,0)
$$ 
for $H$ and $d$ fixed this last expression is polynomial in the coefficients of $Q$.